# What's the best way to flip a single bit in a bitstring?

Tags: string, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bit, bitstring

Say for instance, you have an 8-character string  representing an 8-bit byte; i.e `'00000000'` (0) and you want to flip a single bit, to make it `'00010000'` (16). What's the best or most elegant way to do it?

Comment: Use an `int` instead of a `str`? If you must use `str`, it's still most straightforward to convert to `int` and back, simply because logic with text `0` and `1` is less straightforward than working with actual bits.

Comment: Using a butterfly's wings. https://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: There is not really any satisfactory approach here since strings are immutable.  It will be better to use a library providing a new type such as [bitstring](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring) or [bitarray](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray) (if you want high-level conveniences) or just use integers (if you want speed).

Comment: "Bitstring" doesn't mean "literally a string" just because it has the word string in it. It's a higher level way of talking about however you choose to implement them. An actual string can serve as the implementation, but it's not very good at the job.

Answer (score 1):

When speaking about bit manipulation, classical way to flip single bit at nth position is

```
x ^= 1 << n
```

XOR 1 always flips the bit.
But if you use strings, then every character is not bit, but the whole byte. So you can try string-to-int conversion, using XOR 1 and inserting new symbol back to the string. Or just using if-else statement.